# In R, why do [<-.data.frame` and `$<-.data.frame` behave differently?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

Whilst trying to convert a column of my `data.frame` from strings to date objects I received an unexpected result together with a rather scary warning message:

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(date = c("20070610", "20170611"))
my_dataframe["date"] <- strptime(my_dataframe$date, format = "%Y%m%d")

# Warning message:
# In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "date", value = list(sec = c(NA_real_,  :
#   provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables

my_dataframe

# my_dataframe
#   date
# 1    0
# 2    0
```

However, if I simply replace the `[<-.data.frame` operator with a `$<-.data.frame` operator I receive the result I want and am not warned about any issues:

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(date = c("20070610", "20170611"))
my_dataframe$date <- strptime(my_dataframe$date, format = "%Y%m%d")
my_dataframe

# my_dataframe
#       date
# 1 20070610
# 2 20170611
```

I am now doing this analysis in a completely different way, but I find this difference in behaviour really distressing and would be really grateful if someone could explain why it occurs.

Thanks!

Comment: What's `my_dataframe_1`? Is that a typo or were you working on a different dataframe?

Comment: Have you studied help("[")?

Comment: I found `help("[.data.frame")` more useful.

Comment: For anyone else coming across a similar issue, the critical detail listed in `help("[.data.frame]")` is:  `For [ the replacement value can be a list: each element of the list is used to replace (part of) one column, recycling the list as necessary.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[.data.frame` and `$.data.frame` are different because `[` returns a data frame (list) and `$` returns a vector. The bracket equivalent of `$` is `[[`, and that works as expected. You can also wrap what you're assigning in `list()` to make sure it is recognized as a single column.

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(date = c("20070610", "20170611"))
my_dataframe["date2"] <- strptime(my_dataframe$date, format = "%Y%m%d")
my_dataframe[["date3"]] <- strptime(my_dataframe$date, format = "%Y%m%d")
my_dataframe$date4 <- strptime(my_dataframe$date, format = "%Y%m%d")
my_dataframe["date5"] <- list(strptime(my_dataframe$date, format = "%Y%m%d"))
my_dataframe
#       date date2      date3      date4      date5
# 1 20070610     0 2007-06-10 2007-06-10 2007-06-10
# 2 20170611     0 2017-06-11 2017-06-11 2017-06-11

# [[<-, $<-, and [<- list() all work fine
```

In this case, I think it's the extra attributes of the POSIX class objects that confuse things. In general, best practice is to use `[[` when you know there is a single column.

```
x = strptime(my_dataframe$date, format = "%Y%m%d")
attributes(x)
# $names
#  [1] "sec"    "min"    "hour"   "mday"   "mon"    "year"   "wday"   "yday"   "isdst"  "zone"  
# [11] "gmtoff"
# 
# $class
# [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```